# Password extension error

Tags: bolt-cms

There's not much to describe: 
I have installed the PasswordProtect extension under Bolt 5.0.5, and when I go to the page with the {{ passwordprotect() }} all I get is
http://i.share.pho.to/69d8d8bb_o.png

Is this a bug or is it me?

Comment: There is an undefined function somewhere in the code. The "simpleredirect()" looks strange in the context it is in.

Comment: So where should I start?

Comment: Have you edited any part of the code? It is not a bug, just a simple mistake somewhere. You can comment out parts of that code, and see if you still get the error.

Comment: No, haven't changed anything outside Twig templates - I'm not a php guy. 

My guess is that Simpleredirect has something to do with the "redirect: ..."  in the passwordprotect.bolt.yml file. This line is pointing to an existing page, if you might ask.

Comment: Whoops, looks like I need to update the extension. "simpleredirect" changed a bit. I'll look into this!

Comment: Always reassuring to know that it was not my fault. It's not possible to use multiple passwords for different pages, I understand?

Comment: I have never used it, but yeah, you likely cannot though. I looked at its features and doesn't specify. If you updated any part of it the cms, that could be your error.

Comment: Quick question: When was Bolt 5.0.5 released? (Kidding - it's 2.0.5)